# ssl/tls secure channel not creating

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are getting  The request aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel Error. we are integrating the mapmyindia to get the current location of the vehicles.

My local system is working fine, but the production server does not show the Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel Error. could please help us.

This is my code.

```cs
 const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls11 = 768;
 const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 = 3072;

 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
 (SecurityProtocolType)(SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 | 
 SecurityProtocolTypeTls11) | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

 string MapbasicURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MMIRevGeoAPI"];
 string querystring = "lat=" + latitude + "&" + "lng=" + longitude;
 urlWithGoogleKey = MapbasicURL + querystring;
 request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlWithGoogleKey);
 request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 string responsereader1 = "";
 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {
     TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
     Thread.Sleep(interval);
     using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
         StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
         responsereader1 = sreader.ReadToEnd();
         response.Close();
         sreader.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

could please help this.
Thank you.

I am expecting the where I am done the wrong

Answer (score 0):

It changes according to which .net runtime version installed on your system.

And also you should set secure channel preference in that order. (1.0 | 1.1 | 1.2), I mean; tls | tls11 | tls12.
You can try:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Note: You need to download and install the .Net Framework runtime 4.5 or above on your system. In .Net 4.5 Framework, you will get option for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 but in .Net 4.0 and below versions, the value (TLS11=768, TLS12=3072) needs to be set in the SecurityProtocol as you did.